# How to enforce different stages in pipeline to run on the same Jenkins agent?

Tags: jenkins

My jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {label "master"}
  parameters {
    string(name: "host", defaultValue: "ci_agent_001 || ci_agent_002")
  }
  stages {
    stage ("build") {
    agent ( label "${params.host}" )
    steps {
      script {
        sh "./script.py --build"
      }
    }
  }
    stage ("deploy") {
    agent ( label "${params.host}" )
    steps {
      script {
        sh "./script.py --deploy"
      }
    }
  }
    stage ("test") {
    agent ( label "${params.host}" )
    steps {
      script {
        sh "./script.py --test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each Python script handles all the logic I need, however I must have the same agent to run the stages, and if I allow more than one option in the `host` param, I can't assert the agent stage I got, will be the same agent stage II will get (and without downtime, i.e. I can't allow another job use that agent between my stages).

Can I specify an agent to the whole pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In fact, you can free your master from running pipelines at all:

- Replace `agent {label "master"}` with `agent {label params.host}`
- Clear all the `agent ( label "${params.host}" )` lines inside individual stages (you also don't need the `script` block, as you can run `sh` steps directly within the `steps` block)

If later on you decide you don't want to assign a single node to all stages you'll have to use scripted pipeline inside the declarative pipeline to group stages that should run on the same node:

```
stage("stages that share the same node") {
  agent { label params.host }
  steps {
    script {
      stage("$NODE_NAME - build") {
        sh "./script.py --build"
      }
      stage("$NODE_NAME - deploy") {
        sh "./script.py --deploy"
      }
      stage("$NODE_NAME - test") {
        sh "./script.py --test"
      }
    }
  }
}
stage("look at me I might be on another node") {
  agent { label params.host }
  steps {
    echo NODE_NAME
  }
}
```